# a way to test if prepareForSegue does what it's supposed to

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, storyboard

I'm not sure how to perform a segue inside a unit test so that prepareForSegue will run.

Trying my best to cover everything with Unit Tests, here's what I'm trying:

```
- (void)setUp {

    [super setUp];
    _mainVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]
                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kMainVC];
    _detailsVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]
                      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kDetailsVC];
}

- (void)test_prepareForSegue_will_set_confNumber_on_DetailsVC {

   UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:kDetailsSegueId source:_mainVC destination:_detailsVC performHandler:^{
        // do anything here ???
    }];

    [segue perform];
    expect(_detailsVC.textFieldStr).to.equal(@"123456abc");
}
```

I notice that prepareForSegue in the main viewcontroller is never hit when I put a breakpoint in.

Answer (score 3):

DUH.

just call prepareForSegue on the ViewController under test :)

```
UIStoryboardSegue *segue = [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:kDetailsSegueId source:_mainVC destination:_detailsVC performHandler:^{
        // do nothing here
    }];

[_mainVC prepareForSegue:segue sender:self];
expect(_detailsVC.confNumber).to.equal(@"123456abc");
```